# Yii - возможно ли отобразить результат Action контроллера в layout?

Tags: yii, yii2, mvc

Ситуация такая, что, имея опыт работы с bitrix и внутренним движком компании, привык, что action контроллера (или его подобия - компонента) спокойно вызывается в любой точке любого шаблона и запускается любой указанный шаблон этого самого контроллера.

При этом в Yii ничего подобного не нахожу.

***Вопрос:***
Итак, если мне необходимо в layout помимо отображения $content запрошенного контроллера *(назовем его основным)* отобразить **другую** динамическую информацию *(назовем её дополнительной)*, нужно обязательно **создавать для неё виджет** или, как алтернатива, **создавать ещё один action**, где будут передаваться общие результаты для вывода основной и дополнительной информации?

***К примеру:***
На главной странице помимо текста главной страницы нужно вывести список последних новостей, случайную новость и форму обратной связи, причем **все** они также существуют в виде отдельных страниц с отдельными контроллерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, в Yii2 такие задачи решаются через виджеты.
Если нужно получить доступ к котнроллеру из лейаута или вью, то можно обратится:

```
 $this->context
```

Comment: Уточню: выходит, контроллер используется *только* для запросов?

Comment: В общем как всегда в MVC контроллер для управления данных из модели и подготовке данных для вью

Comment: Это само собой. Но в итоге используется то он лишь для основного контента странички и больше нигде?